# What can we say about the solution to the following linear system ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the linear equation $y'(x)=A(x)y(x)$, $y\in R^n$ and $x\in R$. Assume that $A(x)$ is the $n\times n$ matrix and $\|A\|\le u(x)$ and $u(x)\ge 0$ is a continuous function on $R$ with $\int_0^\infty u(s)ds<\infty$. How to explain the solution?

We can apply Gronwall inequality to bound $|y(x)|$ and get the existence of $\lim_{x\to \infty} y(x)<\infty$. Also, we can check $A(x)$ satisfies
$$
|A(x)-A(x)|\le u(x)|y_1-y_2|
$$

So by [Does my proof prove our statement of the following ODE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4774556/does-my-proof-prove-our-statement-of-the-following-ode), we can find a 1-1 correspondence between the initial value and the limit value of the solution.